# Custom Azure B2C sign up policy - client credential authorisation flow for business logic API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am currently [following this user guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw-secure-basic) for adding a custom policy to my B2C sign up process

I have created the API and configured the various XML files. I can generate a token to access the API via the implict flow.

The API is secured under the app service with Azure Active Directory authentication.

The page linked to describes how to add basic authentication and a client ID / secret, which is a Client Credentials flow, so I was trying to test this in postman

However, having failed to get it to work I went looking and found a variety of posts stating implict credentials are not supported by Azure B2C?

If that is the case I'm puzzled how it is I'm supposed to ensure the claims of the API I am calling to carry out the business logic can be accessed by the custom policy?

My API is hosted on Azure in the same subscription. I can generate tokens for this API fine to use within my native / client app.

Please could someone advise how I should go about testing access to this API from a B2C context via Postman?

Answer (score 0):

> The page linked to describes how to add basic authentication and a client ID / secret, which is a Client Credentials flow, so I was trying to test this in postman

To be exact, it should not be called Client Credentials, because it isn't it.
It's just HTTP Basic authentication.

You are adding an alternative authentication method to your API in that case.
The fact that B2C does not support client credentials auth does not matter here.

What matters is that you have enabled AAD authentication on App Service.
This will block the calls that try to use Basic auth against your API.

Here are a couple options that you can do:

1. Disable authentication on the App Service and implement the two alternative authentication methods in your API code
2. Allow anonymous calls through from App Service auth and implement Basic auth for unauthenticated requests in your API code

As for testing from Postman, it should then be the same as testing any API supporting Basic authentication.
You don't authenticate against B2C, so there is nothing special about it.

Comment: I was using the vocab from Postman that most closely mimicked what I am trying to do - only the Client Credentials option limits the user inputs to client ID and client secret

Comment: Yeah, you should use the HTTP Basic authentication option instead of OAuth.

Comment: OK from what you're saying I don't really have a choice - however I'm unclear what the difference is between option 1 and 2 above, in that I don't really see the difference between disabling AAD auth and allowing anonymous requests. the work of adding basic auth to that API ought to be the same?

Comment: True, but in option 1 you remove it entirely. Option 2 still allows you to use B2C tokens against your API through App Service authentication. So in option 2 you wouldn't need to implement Bearer token authentication in your API.

Comment: Actually one more question - there is an alternate method of authentication, prescribed for the claims ion this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-custom-rest-api-netfw-secure-cert - would this one allow me to keep using AAD to block all unauthorised requests?

Comment: No. The AAD authentication requires a valid token and the certificate is not it. So, you'd still need to modify that somehow.